# Outlook HTML CSS transparent background in cell within table

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

*** UPDATE *** I should've been clearer and perhaps less verbose. The "Web" team w/in the company I work for sent me the HTML. As I said, due to windows (SSIS) -> unix (SAS) -> mainframe (EBCDIC), I can NOT use anything with a !, unless it's content, and then I have to hard code in the ASCII equivalent. So, to shorten my question -- I need to do a table with a nested table that has a background image, and white text on top. This solution needs to work on (nearly) all email & web browser platforms. (We don't care about really old, no longer supported, versions)

**An alternate solution** is if someone knows how to send the EBCDIC code assignment (5A) to pass and not get jacked, again windows->unix->mainframe. I know another team that sends x5A from SAS and it works. I'm really really trying to avoid ingesting the entire file into SAS just to do a find/replace, which would also likely screw up the fixed width file. But I could figure a way around that.
*** /UPDATE ***

I'm bashing my head against the wall here .. I'm writing up HTML to be used as content for emails - in one spot there's a table with a nested table -- the outside has an image, the inside has text (as in, like a text box).

I'm able to get it to work on everything (testing on EmailOnAcid) -- using rgba works, cept for ... yes outlook -- researching this (yay google) I now know Outlook doesn't support rgba. I've tried background-color:transparent. no joy. I've tried opacity:0, but that makes the text transparent (i feel like I'm close on that one, but missing something, maybe obvious)

p.s. don't ask my why the code I was given has 3 redundant references to the background jpg. This content was given to me, and now I have to manhandle it into something that'll work in my system.

Things I can't control -

- I can't get them to make me an image with text over it, they're being weird about it.
- Due to generating the text file which jumps from windows to unix to mainframe I can't use any ! that isn't email content. (i.e. no !important, no !-- comments , which means no if statements within the comment like [if gte mso 9], ...)
- There's a new standard of CSS floating around - I'm not a fan. But other orgs w/in the company don't generate the email text files on a windows server -- they do it in SAS (unix/linux) then to mainframe -- so they can use the ebcdic codes. It just won't work if I do the same in my files. :(

Here's a chunk of the code (with the rgba) -- related css is below it

```
 <table border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="deviceWidth">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td background="http://not.real.path/something.jpg" bgcolor="#c8c7bc" valign="top" width="600" height="258" style="background-image: url(http://not.real.path/something.jpg) no-repeat center center;" id="heroImg" >

                   <div id="txtCntr">
                     <table border="0" width="340" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:50px 5px 10px 25px;display:block;" class="heroTxtTbl">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" valign="middle" style="display:block; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">

                        <p href="#" style="margin:0;padding:5px 0;font-size:45px; line-height: 48px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, Myriad, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;font-weight: bold;" class="heroTxt">We will<br>do something<br>really amazing.</p>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                       </table>

                  </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The background css parts ar:

```
<style>
.deviceWidth {
width:100% ;
height:auto 
}
#heroImg {
display:block;
background-image:url("http://not.real.path/something.jpg");
width:100%;
height: 250px;
padding:0;
}
.heroTxt {
font-size: 38px ;
line-height: 40px ;
}
.heroTxtTbl {
width: 80% ;
float: left;
margin:50px 5px 10px 25px;
display:block;
}
.heroTxtEmp {
font-size: 17px ;
line-height: 22px ;
}
#txtCntr {
padding:5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: post a jsfiddle please. edit: from the looks of it, the table-cell you are trying to make transparent, IS actually transparent. Also, why bother placing the whole .txtCntr element and not just place the text directly on the table-cell that contains the background?

Comment: Instead of re-writing your answer, being more demanding, what if you tried the method I posted below? Try it without if statement for Outlook. If it works, you're golden. If it doesn't, then your email will work with most html email clients except Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook for the last few versions does not support background images, `background-color` (try `background:#ff0000;"`) rgba, padding, margin or fun.

This web site will help you create a background image for Outlook.

https://backgrounds.cm/

This is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/p07yrhbq/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Soo .. I didn't know if the v:rect, v:textbox things would work on their own, without the IF
We tried it

```
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:258px;">
   <v:fill type="tile"src="http://navient.com/assets/images/email/pcc/NVT-17-14574_PCC_hero.jpg" color="#c8c7bc" />
       <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0" style="v-text-anchor:middle">

blah blah tables and text and pix

                  </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
```

and it worked. It didn't seem to corrupt other email clients (tested via emailonacid) ... so we're going with it.

=)